# Show that if a linear transformation sends bases to bases, then it is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to show that if a linear transformation sends bases to bases, then it is bijective.

I have the idea, but can't find a way to prove this.

Can someone help me or give a me a hint?

Comment: What's the idea?

Comment: I think it would be instructive to first show that a linear map carries linearly independent sets iff it is injective; carries spanning sets iff it is surjective and then combine the two results to conclude that it carries basis iff it is bijective. This was the way our linear algebra prof gave us this exercise.

Comment: In the future, please write your question body so that we don't have to reread the title to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ be a basis in the domain such that $\{Ax_1, \ldots, Ax_n\}$ is a basis in the codomain.

For injectivity, we wish to prove that $A$ has trivial kernel. Assume $Ax = 0$ and write $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i$. We have
$$0 = Ax = A\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i Ax_i$$
which implies $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ since $\{Ax_1, \ldots, Ax_n\}$ is linearly independent. Hence $x = 0$.

For surjectivity, any $y$ in the codomain can be written as a linear combination $y = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i Ax_i$ since $\{Ax_1, \ldots, Ax_n\}$ spans the codomain. Then
$$A\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i Ax_i = y$$
so $y$ is in the image of $A$.

Hence $A$ is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we consider finite dimensional spaces to keep the notation approachable. That said, the proof can be extended to the case of arbitrary dimension without too much effort.

Suppose that $T:V \to W$. Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. By the information in the question, $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a basis of $W$. I claim that there is a unique linear transformation $S$ for which
$$
S(Tv_j) = v_j, \quad j = 1,\dots, n.
$$
In particular: because $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a basis, there is indeed such a linear transformation, and $S$ is uniquely specified by this condition.

With that, it suffices to note that $S \circ T$ and $T \circ S$ are identity maps. Since $T$ has an inverse, it must be bijective.